# how can i get page name and add some string in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

My issue: that I have two pages

1- page.aspx for English language mode

2- page-ar.aspx for Arabic language  mode

And I have `LinkeButton` on click I pass session;

```
Session["lang"] = "ar";
```

or

```
Session["lang"] = "en";
```

What I need to get page.aspx name  and add this string "-ar" to goto Arabic mode 
or to remove "-ar" from page-ar.aspx to goto English mode

And take in your consideration maybe there's some query string in pageurl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this the answer after the **Mr/sheKhar** help and with my own search

i have two button

one for Arabic and other for English mode

***when user click on English button***

```
    protected void english_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    System.IO.FileInfo Info = new System.IO.FileInfo(Path);
    string pageName = Info.Name;

    if (Session["lang"].ToString() == "ar")
    {
        string enlink = pageName.Substring(0, pageName.Length - 8) + ".aspx";
        Session["lang"] = "en";

        var page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
        string QueryString = page.ClientQueryString;
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(QueryString)))
        {
            Response.Redirect(enlink + "?" + QueryString);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect(enlink);
        }
    }

}
```

***and when user click on arabic button***

```
 protected void arabic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string Path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    System.IO.FileInfo Info = new System.IO.FileInfo(Path);
    string pageName = Info.Name;

    if (Session["lang"].ToString() == "en")
    {
        string arlink= pageName.Substring(0, pageName.Length - 5) + "-ar.aspx";
        Session["lang"] = "ar";
        //
        var page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
        string QueryString = page.ClientQueryString; // this code get The Query String 

        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(QueryString)))
        {
            Response.Redirect(arlink +"?"+ QueryString);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect(arlink);
        }
    }

}
```

wish this code helping someone :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following code in the code-behind page (e.g. Page_Load):

```
protected string LinkUrl;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var language = (string) Session["lang"] ?? "en";

    LinkUrl = (language == "ar")
                ? Page.ResolveUrl("~/page-ar.aspx")
                : Page.ResolveUrl("~/page.aspx");
}
```

On the page markup you can then place a link like this:

```
 <a href="<%= LinkUrl %>">Language Demo</a>
```

Comment: Does this take querystring into consideration?

Answer (score 1):

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
// http://localhost:1302/TESTERS/Default6.aspx

string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
// /TESTERS/Default6.aspx

string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
// localhost
```

You can create a function which can return the current page name as follows

```
public string GetCurrentPageName()
{
    string Path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    System.IO.FileInfo Info = new System.IO.FileInfo(Path);
    string pageName = Info.Name;
    return pageName;
}
```

Now finaly you can create a function and pass the session value as follows

```
 public string GetCurrentPageName(string fileName)
{
     string Path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    System.IO.FileInfo Info = new System.IO.FileInfo(Path);
    string pageName = Info.Name;
    if (fileName == "ar")
        return pageName.Substring(0, pageName.Length - 7) + ".aspx";
    else
        return pageName.Substring(0, pageName.Length - 5) + "_ar.aspx";    
 }
```

Pass the session value in the above function and it will work.

**Note:- I have not tested it.**

Answer (score 1):

If you are at the beginning of designing your system I would suggest you to use resource **.resx** files.

To make the UI multilanguage with resources check out this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917414

For the data that you pull from the database you will have to use a lot of if statements.

```
If (arabic) {
     Select arabic data
}
else
{
     Select english data
}
```

If you consider to use resx files I can help you with more information.

With this solution there are no string manipulations and querystrings will be fine everything will work.

Comment: thanks man but i'm really my design was finished but i will need to use file resource.resx in the next project :)